# Is casting to array in a foreach considered a bad practise?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, casting

Is it considered a bad practise to cast to an array when initiating a foreach loop. Something like this:

```
foreach ((array) $examples as $example) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This prevents from

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

from occurring.

Or would it be a better practise to check if its an array first:

```
if ( is_array($examples) ) { 
    // Do the loop 
}
```

Comment: An Iterable object, such as a Collection or a Generator, can be looped using `foreach()`, but will return `false` for `is_array()`.... better check by other means

Comment: Is there any context we should know about? When not an array, are you expecting any arbitrary type, including implementations of the `Traversable` interface? Or you just want to e.g. detect when your dataset is empty? Whether it's bad practice or not depends heavily on that. In general, not having the faintest idea of what your internal variables can hold may be a symptom of a design problem that should possibly be addressed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't cast a variable to an array. So you'd better check if it's iterable. You can use this code to check if variable is traversable or usable in foreach:

```
   if( !is_array( $examples ) && !$examples instanceof Traversable )
```

Comment: I don't know the reason for doewvote, will you show it.

Comment: Seems like a good approach to me. In which case would a variable be unable to cast to an array? What if I'm 100% certain the variable is either an array or a string? Also is `is_array` necessary when checking if its an instance of `Traversable`