# Best way to check if variable is set and can be 'foreach'ed

Tags: php

I've taken over a larger code base, that has several warnings and errors.

I keep running into statements like this:

```php
foreach( $object->keys => $key ){
  ...
}
```

Where I can see in the error log, that `$object` is null.

What is the simplest way, tot check that above-written statement won't break?

---

To be 100% sure, I would do something like this:

```php
if( isset( $object ) && is_array( $object->keys ) ){
  foreach( $object->keys => $key ){
    ...
  }
}
```

But the readability decreases significantly.

I could also make a helper function, that did it, like so:

```php
if( myHelper::canBeForeached( $object, 'keys' ) ){ // naming would obviously be changed
  foreach( $object->keys => $key ){
    ...
  }
}
```

But that too seems bad.

What is the simplest/prettiest way to achieve this, to also maintain readability of the code?

Comment: Perhaps something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42667976/296555, but the better solution is to fix the underlying code issues that produce different data types. This may be a big undertaking on large projects though.

Comment: ```foreach( $object->keys => $key )``` is a syntax error? Did you mean ```as $key```? In any case, the short way (that feels a bit dirty) is null coalescing, ie. ```foreach($object->keys ?? [] as $key) {```, ie. if `$object` or `keys` is not defined, you provide `[]` an empty array, which obviously just won't be iterated. This assumes that if `$object` exists and `->keys` exists, `keys` will be iterable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to approach this. Here's the shortest approach.

If you use the `??` null-coalescing operator for default value, in the event that either `$object` or `->keys` is undefined, then `[]` or an empty array will be passed for iteration, and obviously nothing happens. This is one way to avoid wrapping your `foreach` loop inside a condition.

```
foreach($object->keys ?? [] as $key) {
    // If $object or ->keys is undefined, nothing happens.
}
```

Now, some may object that this is *unclear* or *unreadable*; but at least it's not a ton of boilerplate, and it's very quick to add in. This approach assumes that if `$object` exists and has the property `keys`, then `keys` will be iterable. If not, it will result in a warning on *must be of type array|object*.

Other than that, you'd have to wrap all your loops with a condition check, `isset($object)`, or alternatively, `gettype($object) === 'object'` if you want to ensure that it's an object. For some reason, `is_object()` will give a warning for an undefined variable. Again, `is_null()` returns `true` if the variable is undefined, essentially behaving like `!isset()` when negated.

As noted above, if your legacy code has objects with plural-named properties that are *not iterable but also not null* (e.g. `->keys = 'duck'`), you'll have to do a check on your `$object->keys` with [`is_iterable()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php) before it enters the loop for an attempt at iteration.

If you pass an undefined object into `is_iterable`, it's a warning again. You can, however, use the power of null-coalescing once more, where if either `$object` or `->keys` is undefined, the check below reads as `is_iterable(false)` (or any other non-iterable value to evaluate):

```
if(is_iterable($object->keys ?? false)) { 
    foreach($object->keys as $key) {
    //...
    }
}
```

...and that could be the sole condition that wraps your loop.

P.S. On the possible solutions in OP: A helper function results in warnings if used with an undefined variable. Also, your `if( isset( $object ) && is_array( $object->keys ) )` will result in a warning if `object` is defined but doesn't have the `->keys` property.

Comment: Wrote a related answer on using null-coalescence to provide default values, at OP's question on [Muting / ignoring PHP Notices from a part of my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70906701/muting-ignoring-php-notices-from-a-part-of-my-code)